# Upgrading a PC running Windows 7 BIOS to run Windows 10 UEFI?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, bios, uefi, upgrade

I am a longtime macOS user with some experience running Linux in the cloud – so the low-level details of Windows, BIOS, and UEFI are typically above my paygrade. Nonetheless:

I have a PC that is currently running Windows 7, from an internal hard drive set up with an MBR partition scheme, which boots from BIOS. I’ve created a bootable Windows 10 USB installer from an image I downloaded from Microsoft, but alas: it doesn’t know how to contend with the internal drives’ legacy configuration, and the installer won’t proceed past the volume-selection phase.

I take it that I need to create another USB drive from an image that contains, like, some UEFI-aware utilities that can reformat and update the drive – to e.g. a GUID-mapped, UEFI-partitioned setup or somesuch.

My question, in two parts, is:

1. Am I correct in these assumptions, or do I need to take additional measures to accomplish this upgrade? And
2. Where can I obtain such a utility toolset, either freely or cheaply?

Comment: Are you trying to upgrade the existing Windows 7 installation or to install a brand new Windows 10 on this disk?

Comment: You would first need to find out if your motherboard supports UEFI and is currently running in BIOS compatibility mode, or if it is simply BIOS-only. In your firmware setup you may see "legacy BIOS", "CSM", "compatibility support module" or similar if it is the former. Turning those options off should switch to UEFI, at which point you will have to wipe your disk and reinstall. If you do not have one of those options then UEFI may well be out of your reach.

Answer (score 2):

You don't change BIOS to UEFI - its the firmware. I suspect the issue is between GPT and non GPT installs. [Rufus](https://rufus.ie) is pretty good at handling most of the complexity - it even downloads the ISO.

[image]

The settings below seem *reasonably* sensible. You want a BIOS compatible installer, and MBR, not GPT on an older machine, unless you wanted to wipe it.

Comment: You _can_ change the installed system from having a BIOS-compatible bootloader to an UEFI-compatible bootloader though. Earlier it was not uncommon for computers to have UEFI firmware but but still be sold with Windows installed in BIOS/CSM mode, and the firmware set to "Legacy boot only" or something like that, because the manufacturer couldn't be bothered... And it sounds like that's what OP has – an UEFI PC which is currently booting Windows in BIOS/CSM mode.

Answer (score 1):

It's indeed possible that your PC is booting on your hard drive using UEFI, and wants to boot on USB in legacy BIOS mode.
You should check your system's boot menu options, and stating what your computer actually is would help here.

It could also be a totally different problem, like Windows 10 not being able to cope with the current partition layout, for any reason.
Wiping the existing partitions (assuming you can afford to get rid of existing data) could help.

Another much simpler option would be to just run the Windows 10 setup from the running Windows 7 system and see what happens.